# BigCommerce Auth Callback URI, Load Callback URI and Uninstall Callback URI

Tags: bigcommerce

During BigCommerce App registration the Auth Callback URI, Load Callback URI and Uninstall Callback URI should be provided.
After registering the app can I change the URIs before App submission?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change URIs before app submission. It may require you to reinstall the app on any store where you might've been testing it.

Comment: Is it possible to use separate URL for install/uninstall (A diff. app) and for load (Another app which just uses the payload provided by BigCommerce). Basically I want to load another app inside the iframe, and i do not want to bind it directly with BigCommerce, so thinking to use it as load callback.